# PCL 1.8 Normal estimation. Are normals estimated correctly?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I found out that when I do normal estimation to my point cloud I sometimes get couple (1-4) very long normals stretching towards origin (I assume its towards origin). I think this does not happen every time when running for the same cloud.

Is there some sort of reasonable explanation for this?

Code and image below: (The cloud is read from pcd-file)

```
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normal_estimate;
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>());
normal_estimate.setSearchMethod(tree);
normal_estimate.setInputCloud(cloud);
normal_estimate.setRadiusSearch(0.02);
normal_estimate.compute(*cloud_normals);
```

Image: [One normal sticking towards origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKV4.png)

Comment: Why should one assume there is an error? Also, questions must be self-contained. External resources can sometimes be used as supplements, but the question itself must contain sufficient details for an answer to be given.

Comment: Would my question be better now? I am not assuming errors. Probably its me who has done something wrong. This may be very beginner level question related to the library..

Comment: Consider this hypothesis: the very long normals stretching toward origin are an accurate representation of your data. How would you shoot that hypothesis down? (Sure, it *looks* wrong, but "looking" is not a good basis for debugging.)